# Angular - Hide Guarded Links in template

Tags: angular, typescript, roles, angular-routing

I have an AuthGuard that implements CanActivate, which returns true or false depending on some custom logic:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

import { UserTypes } from '../model/user-type';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const allowedRoles = route.data['allowedRoles'] as Array<UserTypes>;
        if (!allowedRoles) {
            // All users allowed
            return true;
        }
        // Check user's role against the allowed roles defined
        const canActivate = (allowedRoles.indexOf(this.authService.userData.UserTypeId) !== -1);
        if (!canActivate) {
            this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
        }
        return canActivate;
    }
}
```

I need both `canActivate` parameters (`route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot`) for processing (not all code is shown).

My routes are defined with some route data telling me which user types can access a route. This all works perfectly fine when trying to access routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PortalLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: PortalDashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'customers',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { allowedRoles: [UserTypes.Admin] },
        children: [
          { path: '', component: PortalCustomerListComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

If - for any given link - canActivate returns false, I want to hide the link in the template. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Here's a typical link in a template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['customers']">List Customers</a>
```

How would I go about disabling this without repeating the user type logic I've put into the AuthGuard? I have attempted to inject AuthGuard into my components, but I can't figure out how I would provide the two params needed by canActivate? Here's an example component with some test code I'm currently trying to get working:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Constants } from '../../app.constants';

import { AuthGuard } from '../../guards/auth.guard';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './portal-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portal-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class PortalDashboardComponent {
  constructor(
    private authGuard: AuthGuard,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  public get canActivateLink(targetUrl: string): boolean {
    **// TODO: Use targetLink here to get user role rules from the route data?** 
    return this.authGuard.canActivate(this.activatedRoute.snapshot, this.router.routerState.snapshot);
  }
}
```

If I could get the above working, I would simply do the following in the template (not 100% DRY, but beats putting repeat role logic into the controller for every link):

```
<a [routerLink]="['customers']" *ngIf="canActivateLink('customers')">List Customers</a>
```

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get this working as a directive thanks to Yordan. However, I still have exactly the same issue, in that I can't figure out an easy way to get Route information (i.e. the route data) for a specific URL. Here's what I've got so far:

```
import { Input, OnInit, Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService, AuthState } from '../../services/auth.service';

import { UserTypes } from '../../model/user-type';

@Directive({
    selector: '[hiddenIfUnauthorised]'
})
export class HiddenIfUnauthorisedDirective implements OnInit {

    private commands: any[] = [];

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private locationStrategy: LocationStrategy,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private auth: AuthService
    ) { }

    @Input()
    set hiddenIfUnauthorised(commands: any[] | string) {
        if (commands != null) {
            this.commands = Array.isArray(commands) ? commands : [commands];
        } else {
            this.commands = [];
        }
        console.log(this.commands);
    }

    get urlTree(): UrlTree {
        // TODO: Mimic the rest of the relevant options as per the RouterLink source
        return this.router.createUrlTree(this.commands, {
            relativeTo: this.route
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        const urlTree = this.urlTree;
        const sUrl = this.router.serializeUrl(urlTree);
        const url = this.locationStrategy.prepareExternalUrl(sUrl);

        // TODO: I need to generate an ActivatedRoute object for the "url" created above
        // so I can get 'allowedRoles' from route data - or get it some other way.
        // Are there any helper methods anywhere?
        const targetRoute = this.route;

        const userTypes = targetRoute.data['allowedRoles'] as Array<UserTypes>;

        const authState = this.auth.getAuthState(userTypes);

        if (authState !== AuthState.Authorised) {
            // Not authorised, remove the DOM container
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        } else {
            // Show the DOM container
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

This is registered in my module, then used in a template as follows:

```
<div *hiddenIfUnauthorised="['customers']">
Secure Content!
</div>
```

Still looking for a solution, if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to make a directive like [authUrl]. In these directive to instantiate your Auth service and check the user permissions and based on this you can show/hide any element on the page.

Comment: Not tackled directives yet - I'll look them up now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick code of what I meant

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[permission]' })
export class IfDirective {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private auth: AuthService
    ) { }

  @Input() permission: string;

  public ngOnInit() {
    if(this.auth.hasPermission) {
      // If condition is true add template to DOM
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
     } else {
     // Else remove template from DOM
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

}
```

Edited

Comment: Good info, but not quite what I'm looking for - I need to be able to retrieve the routing data so I can check a link against it for the current user's userType.

Comment: im not in front of the computer right now, but I'm pretty sure that you can inject the `ActivatedRouter` and get the current route. You can pass the router like `@Input()` property even

Comment: How to use this directive?